# Function-Based-Index when using IN subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, subquery, oracle12c

I'm have the following code

```
WITH T AS(
          SELECT SOMETHING 
)
SELECT * FROM tab1 t1
LEFT JOIN tab2 t2 on t1.ID = t2 .ID
LEFT JOIN tab3 t3 on t1.ID = t3 .ID
LEFT JOIN tab4 t4 on t1.ID = t4.ID
LEFT JOIN tab5 t5 on t1.ID = t5.ID
INNER JOIN tempo_tab6 t6 on t1.ID = t6.ID
LEFT JOIN tab7 t7 on t1.ID = t7.ID
WHERE t1.Col1 = 0
AND t1.Col2 = 1
AND t1.Col3 IN (SELECT t8.Col FROM tab8 t8 WHERE Col ='ABC')
```

When I execute the Advisor, It advised me create FBI in ID.Col3, but my company rule isn't accept FBI In any case. Is there any way to solve this? It took 18s for some values without Index.

Many thanks.

Edit: this is the execution plan of this case.

```
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1976489795
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                               | Name                                    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                        |                                         |     1 |   873 | 11730   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TEMP TABLE TRANSFORMATION              |                                         |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   LOAD AS SELECT                        | SYS_TEMP_1FD9EE041_D91A3E0              |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    HASH UNIQUE                          |                                         |     1 |   436 |    15   (7)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN                |                                         |     1 |   436 |    14   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |      HASH JOIN OUTER                    |                                         |     1 |   436 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   6 |       NESTED LOOPS                      |                                         |     1 |   220 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   7 |        NESTED LOOPS                     |                                         |     1 |   217 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   8 |         NESTED LOOPS                    |                                         |     1 |   209 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  9 |          TABLE ACCESS FULL              | TMP_REPORT                              |     1 |   204 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 10 |          INDEX UNIQUE SCAN              | PK_STOCK_ID                             |     1 |     5 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 11 |         INDEX RANGE SCAN                | IX_LS_STOCK_ZONE_FK_STOCK_ID_FK_ZONE_ID |     1 |     8 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 12 |        INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                | PK_ZONE_ID                              |     1 |     3 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 13 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL                 | TMP_REPORT                              |     1 |   216 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  14 |      BUFFER SORT                        |                                         | 12727 |       |    12   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  15 |       INDEX FAST FULL SCAN              | PK_STOCK_DEPARTMENT_ID                  | 12727 |       |     9   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  16 |   COUNT                                 |                                         |       |       |            |          |
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|* 17 |    HASH JOIN SEMI                       |                                         |     1 |   873 | 11715   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  18 |     MERGE JOIN OUTER                    |                                         |     1 |   669 | 11713   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  19 |      NESTED LOOPS OUTER                 |                                         |     1 |   354 | 11709   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  20 |       NESTED LOOPS OUTER                |                                         |     1 |   284 | 11708   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  21 |        NESTED LOOPS OUTER               |                                         |     1 |   264 | 11707   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  22 |         NESTED LOOPS OUTER              |                                         |     1 |   237 | 11706   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  23 |          NESTED LOOPS OUTER             |                                         |     1 |   180 | 11705   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  24 |           NESTED LOOPS OUTER            |                                         |     1 |   166 | 11704   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  25 |            NESTED LOOPS OUTER           |                                         |     1 |   141 | 11703   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  26 |             NESTED LOOPS OUTER          |                                         |     1 |   123 | 11702   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|* 27 |              HASH JOIN                  |                                         |     1 |   100 | 11701   (1)| 00:00:01 |
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  28 |               VIEW                      |                                         |     1 |    26 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  29 |                TABLE ACCESS FULL        | SYS_TEMP_1FD9EE041_D91A3E0              |     1 |    18 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 30 |               TABLE ACCESS FULL         | LS_ITEM_DETAILS                         |   870K|    61M| 11696   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  31 |              TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| LS_ZONES                                |     1 |    23 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 32 |               INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | PK_ZONE_ID                              |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  33 |             TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | LS_INCIDENTS                            |     1 |    18 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 34 |              INDEX UNIQUE SCAN          | PK_INCIDENT_ID                          |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  35 |            TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | LS_EMPLOYEES                            |     1 |    25 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 36 |             INDEX UNIQUE SCAN           | PK_EMPLOYEE_ID                          |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  37 |           TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   | LS_PROJECTS                             |     1 |    14 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 38 |            INDEX UNIQUE SCAN            | PK_PROJECT_ID                           |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  39 |          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID    | LS_STOCKS                               |     1 |    57 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 40 |           INDEX UNIQUE SCAN             | PK_STOCK_ID                             |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  41 |         TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID     | LS_PLANS                                |     1 |    27 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 42 |          INDEX UNIQUE SCAN              | PK_PLAN_ID                              |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  43 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID      | LS_GROUPS                               |     1 |    20 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 44 |         INDEX UNIQUE SCAN               | PK_GROUP_ID                             |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  45 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID       | LS_ITEMS                                |     1 |    70 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 46 |        INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                | ITEM_CODE_UNI                           |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  47 |      BUFFER SORT                        |                                         |     2 |   630 | 11712   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  48 |       VIEW                              | VW_LAT_B17BD126                         |     2 |   630 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  49 |        VIEW                             | VW_ORE_F374A3FE                         |     2 |   630 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  50 |         UNION-ALL                       |                                         |       |       |            |          |
|* 51 |          FILTER                         |                                         |       |       |            |          |
|  52 |           TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   | LS_SUPPLIERS                            |     1 |    51 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 53 |            INDEX UNIQUE SCAN            | PK_SUPPLIER_ID                          |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 54 |          FILTER                         |                                         |       |       |            |          |
|  55 |           TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   | LS_SUPPLIERS                            |     1 |    51 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 56 |            INDEX UNIQUE SCAN            | PK_SUPPLIER_ID                          |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 57 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL                   | TMP_REPORT                              |     1 |   204 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The advisor suggest me create this FBI:

create index ISCHN.IDX$$_25380001 on ISCHN.LS_ITEM_DETAILS(SYS_OP_C2C("SERIAL"));

Comment: that is odd.  can you please edit the question and post the explain plan

Comment: btw, there's not table or table alias `ID`.

Comment: And what is the index definition exactly that is suggested? I can't think of any function that would be helpful here.

Comment: @OldProgrammer here you are, I was update the plan.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan: sr for my mistake, I edited it already